# Displaying certain parameters of the objects of an arraylist into a list view in Android

Tags: java, android, list, view

I have this ArrayList that is displayed in a listview. Right now it works but it shows some kind of array id looking names thats why I wanted it to display the names of each object in the array list (String name).

Each of the Product object has a String name, and other values.

Here is the **ProductList** class where it contains the ArrayList of Products and a method to transfer the names into a String array:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductList {
    ArrayList<Product> list;


public ProductList (){
    list = new ArrayList<Product>();

    //CREATE PRODUCT HERE
    Product chicken;
    list.add(new Product("Chicken", 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 80,70,60,50,40,30));    

    Product rice;
    list.add(new Product("Rice",11));
}

public String[] getNames (){
    int c = 0;
    int size = list.size() - 1;
    String[] names = new String[size];

    while (size >= c) {
        //names.add(list.get(c).getName());
        names[c] = list.get(c).getName();
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;

    return names;
}

public ArrayList<Product> getList (){
    return list;
}
```

}

Finally, here's the code for my ListActivity:

```
public class ProductListView extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ProductList pl = new ProductList();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this, R.layout.list_item, pl.getList() ));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Product product = pl.getList().get(position);
        // intent stuff for product detail
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductListView.this, productdetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",product.getName());
        intent.putExtra("serving size", product.getServingSize());
        intent.putExtra("calories", product.getCalories());
        intent.putExtra("fat", product.getFat());
        intent.putExtra("saturated fat", product.getSaturatedFat());
        intent.putExtra("trans fat", product.getTransFat());
        intent.putExtra("cholesterol", product.getCholesterol());
        intent.putExtra("sodium", product.getSodium());
        intent.putExtra("carbs", product.getCarbs());
        intent.putExtra("fiber", product.getFiber());
        intent.putExtra("sugar", product.getSugar());
        intent.putExtra("protein", product.getProtein());
        intent.putExtra("vitamina", product.getVitaminA());
        intent.putExtra("vitaminc", product.getVitaminC());
        intent.putExtra("calcium", product.getCalcium());
        intent.putExtra("iron", product.getIron());

        ProductListView.this.startActivity(intent);

        //startActivity(new Intent("kfc.project.productdetail"));
      }

    });

}
```

}

I also tried getting all of the String name of each item in the ArrayList and putting them into a String array (using my getNames() method which returns a String array) and then plugging it into the listview, but it just shows an error when I run it:

```
final ProductList pl = new ProductList();

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, pl.getNames() ));
```

Comment: so what's the error showed in LogCat?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the problem is here:

```
public String[] getNames (){
    int c = 0;
    int size = list.size() - 1; <-- size problem
    String[] names = new String[size]; <-- well @@

    while (size >= c) {
        //names.add(list.get(c).getName());
        names[c] = list.get(c).getName(); <-- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, I guess
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;

    return names;
}
```

You see it, don't you?

Here the fix:

```
public String[] getNames (){
    int c = 0;
    int size = list.size(); 
    String[] names = new String[size]; 

    while (size > c) {
        //names.add(list.get(c).getName());
        names[c] = list.get(c).getName(); 
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;

    return names;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked it I guess

Answer (score 1):

The standard ArrayAdapter will automatically use the toString method of the object you have provided in the ArrayList. This means that it is using the default implementation of the toString method in Java which is to display a bunch of nonsense about the object. The simplest way to get it to display the name of the product would be to override the toString method inside of the product object to return only the name of the object.

Ex:

```
    public class Product{

            //Some of your current code for product object

            @Override
            public String toString(){

                    return name;

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, pl.getNames()));
```

Instead of pl.getList().getNames().

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the code in the question. Thats what I've been trying out but the app just crashes when I try to access the listview