# Why is java.lang.String[] not recognizing one of its methods?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a program that uses an arrayList and I am looking for a way to get the names of the arrays within the arrayList. My solution to this problem was to use the following code:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++)
  {
    String name = events.get(i).getName();
    if(name.equals(eventLabel))
    {
      frame3.getContentPane().add(buttons);
    }
  }
```

FYI, events is the arrayList, frame3 is a gridLayout, and eventLabel is what the name should be. 
I get an error on the .getName() saying --> cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getName()
location: class java.lang.String[]. I don't understand why this does not work, it seems to work in this example: [Displaying certain parameters of the objects of an arraylist into a list view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336075/displaying-certain-parameters-of-the-objects-of-an-arraylist-into-a-list-view-in). Alternative solutions for finding the name of the arrays in my arrayList would be appreciated.

EDIT:

It appears this method will not get me the names of the arrays as I wanted. Best answer will be that which shows me how to find the name of a given array in my arrayList called events.

Comment: What `event` list contains ?

Comment: It contains one dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

> events.get(i).getName();

by

> events.get(i).getClass().getName();

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like `getName() for String type in java` because of that its showing in that example `List` is not containing `String` types.